# How to connect desktop computer to TV via HDMI using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, hdmi

Reading other replies to similar posts, they suggest going to display in settings and selecting mirror but it's no longer an option as the layout has changed. Connecting the HDMI cord, their is no signal on the TV, it just displays a black screen.

Comment: When I connect an HDMI cord to my Ubuntu system, everything works properly and I get to watch movies easily. Have you checked the cable to ensure it's not shorted? Have you checked /var/log/syslog tosee of the HDMI connection is detected?

Comment: It can't be shorted as it works when connected to a laptop with Win10. What should I look for exactly in the syslog file? Thanks

Comment: command xrandr outputs HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)